# Send shell to server via SMS

Tags: 12.04, command-line, sms

Hi this might be a duplicate and if so I'd really appreciate if I could get refereed to that question.

So I'm looking for some way to connect a phone to my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server and send shell commands to it via SMS.

Can't seem to find a program that does that. Could someone recommend one?

Thanks in advance,
Carl

Comment: There are ssh clients for android and ios. Is that what you're talking about. Please edit your question to clarify

Answer (score 1):

There are loads of SMS gateway services. These companies charge a small amount to provide you with a HTTP method to retrieve SMS messages sent to one of their phone numbers.

The charge is small (2p a message on one I was looking at) and usually without an ongoing commitment... But this is something that can add up.

Alternatively, if you have a GSM modem and a valid SIM card, you could look at `gsmsmsd`. IMO the gateway is going to be more reliable but the modem might be cheaper at scale (there are many plans with unlimited messaging).

Comment: I believe if you have google hangouts connected to your phone, it can accept SMS's for you and are retrievable through their API

Answer (score 1):

I actually built a ssh via sms service called [smsh](https://github.com/strix/smsh) a while back.  It's built on nodejs and has a sort of 2 factor authentication (a list of allowed phone numbers and a password prepending each command sent).  It uses the [twilio](https://www.twilio.com/) api behind the scenes.  Configuring it is extremely easy and it's worked pretty well for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can a [SSH](http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/Secure-Shell) server on your Ubuntu machine and a SSH client on the phone for that. For the SSH server, you can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

For the SSH client on the phone, [ConnectBot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.connectbot) for Android works brilliantly (particularly with ['Hacker's Keyboard'](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard) for typing `|`, `<` and stuff). There are clients for other systems, like [these two](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/the-two-best-ssh-clients-for-ios-go-head-to-head-prompt-vs-cathode/) mentioned for iOS.

Comment: Yeah I already have ssh but I want to be able to text it aswell.